# send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB) doesn't work in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to switch tabs on chrome by using the following code.

```
driverlist = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window(driverlist[1])
```

which works perfectly fine. But I want write a function when called switches to the next immediate tab, which is I'm trying to use send_keys functions like

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

I'm expecting send_keys() to switch the tab focus to the next tab but when i print current_url, the focus stays on the previous tab.

Comment: I think it should be .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.TAB)

Comment: I have tried that one too, but it simply doesn't do anything

Comment: `driver.switch_to_window()` should switch the windows while `send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")` open new window. These are not the same... What exactly *doesn't work*?

Comment: As i mentioned in the title send_keys(Keys.CONTROL) doesn't work...send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t") is just another example that i have tried.

Comment: @Girishvenkata , what do you mean by *"doesn't work."*? What you expect `send_keys()` to do in this case?

Comment: `send_keys(Keys.CONTROL)` doesn't work isn't very specific or clear. How would you validate if just the CTRL key was pressed? Please edit your question, including the title, and clarify

Comment: @Andersson i want send_keys() to shift the focus of the driver

Comment: @JeffC my apologies i have edited the title now. I just want send_keys() function to shift the tab focus to the next tab

Comment: could you please edit the question and add your error?

Comment: If `.switch_to_window()` is working, why are you trying to use CTRL+T?

Comment: @Girishvenkata , you want WebDriver to physically switch to another tab?

Comment: @JeffC i want to write a function for it and I can't go by specifying the window index everytime i use it. Instead CTRL + TAB (not CTRL+T) would automatically switch it right?

Comment: @Andersson Yes that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: Why can't you specify the index each time? Just write a function that stores the current window handle and loops through window handles until you have a handle that isn't current. Now you know that you have switched handles.

Comment: @JeffC The function i'm writing is a part of script that is used for automated testing, that is the reason i want to skip sepcifying the index. How can I know which handle is the current one?

Comment: `driver.current_window_handle` from [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_window_handle)